# Mime type for excel 2007

Tags: excel, types, header, mime

How can I set the correct MIME type that works with excel 2007?
right now I have this:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
```

my browser keeps telling me that is a 97 2003 file, but when I try to open the file with excel 2007, the program shows some warning, I can see the document, but I'm trying to avoid that warning.

Comment: Are you sending an actual Excel file, or a HTML table posing as an Excel file? Office 2007+ has "extension hardening" which makes sure the content of the file actually matches what it's saying it is... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

Comment: I think that is my problem. I have a php file that contains header info and one html table that contains the info thatI want to send to excel 2007. The link that you pointed shows the XML BIFF8, now I'm checking info about that.

Comment: Some idea? i can't figure it out how to do it..

Comment: If extension hardening is set to the option which prevents anything other than an actual Excel file from opening, then you have to output the expected format. I'm not familiar enough with php to ffer any suggestions there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=936496

Comment: I try with that definition but I'm having troubles with the extension of the file.. Now I trying with xlsx but doesn't work eathier.

Comment: Is the document definitely an OfficeOpenXML file? What "warning" are you getting?

Comment: and the extension of file to ".xlsx" in order to work with excel 2007 but... when I download the file and then try to open it, i get a message from ms excel tells me that can't open the file becouse the format or the extension aren't accepted.

Comment: If the problem is limited to your own computer, the easiest solution could be changing a registry key as described in 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx

Comment: Works for me. @CamiloSalas you should mark this as an answer if it worked.